# Discord.JS Getting presence largeImage

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am attempting to get the largeImage photo from a users status [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3md3c.png)

When logging it to console it returns `spotify:ab67616d0000b27391eb833af3d3829f42321996`
is there anyway to get this in a photo form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`largeImageURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/RichPresenceAssets?scrollTo=largeImageURL) function.